# Django REST Framework, PUT/POST serializer data disappearing

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble with part of my data disappearing when I try to update or post a new instance.

With data like this

```
data = {
        'item': 'Product', 
        'station': 'Workbench', 
        'ingredients':[
            {'item': 'ing1', 'amount': 2},
            {'item': 'ing2', 'amount':1}
         ]
        }
```

I have a serializer with a nested serializer that get_or_creates ingredients as needed.

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('item', 'amount')


class WriteableRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Item.objects.all())
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)
    station = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Item.objects.all())

    def create(self, validated_data):
        logger.info(validated_data)
        ingredient_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for ingredient in ingredient_data:
            ingredient_item = Item.objects.get(name=ingredient['item'])
            amount = ingredient['amount']
            ingredient, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(item=ingredient_item, amount=amount
                                   )
            recipe.ingredients.add(ingredient)

        return recipe

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        logger.info(validated_data)
        ingredient_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        instance.item = validated_data.get('item', instance.item)
        instance.station = validated_data.get('station', instance.station)

        for ingredient in ingredient_data:
            ingredient_item = Item.objects.get(name=ingredient['item'])
            amount = ingredient['amount']
            ingredient, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(item=ingredient_item, amount=amount)
            logger.info('Itering')
            instance.ingredients.add(ingredient)

        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('item', 'amount', 'ingredients', 'station')
```

The data validates and I get a response code 200, but both the response data and the validated_data a shown by my logger in the create and update methods return something like this:

```
    data = {
        'item': 'Product', 
        'station': 'Workbench', 
        'ingredients':[]
        }
```

The Ingredients data going AWOL somewhere.
I have tried making the Ingredient Serializer a generic serializer as well as overriding WriteableRecipeSerializer's validation to just return attrs but the problem persists.

Edit for models:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name + '(' + str(self.amount) + ')'

class Recipe(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, related_name='recipe', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
    station = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='as_station')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Recipe: ' + str(self.item)
```

Comment: Can you post Ingredient and Recipe models also?

Comment: I added the models, thanks